# Use Array in HTML URL

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

Here is my Javascript at the top in the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var myGallery=new Array();
            myGallery[0]="../images/gallery2/2009_09_04-BretErnst_0013.jpg"; 
</script>
```

Now I want to be able to call myGallery[0] and use that as a href.

So I try:

```
<li>
    <a href="myGallery[0]" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="You can add caption to pictures. You can add caption to pictures. You can add caption to pictures.">
        <img src="myGallery[0]" width="60" height="60" alt="Red round shape" />
    </a>
</li>
```

But the variable is not being replaced with the string...

Help?

Comment: You have to do `document.getElementById('myGallery[0]').href = myGallery[0];`

Comment: The HTML is already rendered before you are able to do anything with javascript. Hence you are just adding some string to HTML.

Comment: Well, you could learn how javascript and html interact by googling some tutorials. You cannot do it the way you are trying to do it because this isn't a serverside language like PHP.

Comment: I ended up just doing it in .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about  `<a href="" onclick="location.href=myGallery[0];return false;">image</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to get the value like

```
function loadPic(index){
  window.location = myGallery[index];
}
```

And call the function from the link.

`onclick = "loadPic(0)"`